# Using 'Async Tasks' on Android to generate random number and output

Tags: android, asynchronous, random

I am writing an random number generator program to show the output every sec.

The overview is that every second when the random number change I would want to random number to be output to the 'EditText' box. Is it possible?

I have research on it but result in unsuccessfully (mainly because of how the async works).

This is the code that I have written:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AsyncTasksActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtMessage;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);         

    String ranString = "";

    try{
        ranString = "";
        for(int a = 0; a < 33; a++)
        {
        Random rn = new Random();
        int i = rn.nextInt(256);

        ranString = ranString + i + " ";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    txtMessage.setText(ranString);
}

public class runRandomly extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    }


}
```

In case you need to run the code to ensure it works, I have place the xml code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Null"
/>
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/Null"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
android:text="Random Key"/>
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/txtMessage"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:gravity="center"
android:editable="false" android:layout_height="61dp" android:layout_weight="0.14"/>

<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>   

</LinearLayout>
```

Much Thanks!

Comment: You're very close. Just make a quick guess. I'm pretty sure you can come up with a better partial answer yourself. What code would make sense inside doInBackground? And what code would make sense inside of onProgressUpdate? If you're not comfortable with writing actual code, just write some tentative commmented-out pseudocode inside those two methods. We can help you do the rest.

Comment: doInBackground - means that the random number that is contently running while the progressUpdate is the one that send the update to the UI?

Comment: @Ezylryb: look at my edited answer, use that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view,

1. Make a constructor of your AsyncTask class passing activity signature,
   like,

   ```
   public runRandomly(Activity activity) {
   this.activity = activity;
   context = activity;
   }
   ```
2. also override this method

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
   {

   super.onProgressUpdate(values);
   if (values[0] == 0) {
   mDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
   }

   mDialog.setProgress(values[0]);

   }
   ```
3. update the onProgressUpdate(call it) from your doInBackground(String... params)  method

EDIT: you can also give a reference of your EditText view in AsyncTask constructor and do update in onProgressUpdate method.

EDIT: use this code..

```
public class NewClass extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText edt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.newclass);
    edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed);

    new runRandomly(this,edt).execute();
}


public class runRandomly extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

String ranString="";
Activity activity;
EditText edtt;

public runRandomly(Activity activity,EditText edit) {
    this.activity = activity;
    edtt=edit;
    }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{

        for(int a = 0; a < 33; a++)
        {
        Random rn = new Random();
        int i = rn.nextInt(256);

        ranString = ranString + i + " ";

        }
        onProgressUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    edtt.setText(""+ranString);
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

}


}
```

Simple, Thanx.

Comment: What if I want to start at every 10 seconds and for every minute that passed subtract 1 second from the 10 seconds until it is down to 1 second?

Answer (score 0):

put this line outside of the for loop it will re-generate new object so no need it in loop

```
Random rn = new Random();

for(int a = 0; a < 33; a++)
{
    int i = rn.nextInt(256);

    ranString = ranString + i + " ";
}
```

you need to Handler and Runnable object which call the AsynTask execute method using runRandomly object

like create this object

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
runRandomly randomly = new runRandomly();


Runnable callRandom = new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
        //// call the execute method 
        randomly.execute();
        ///// here handler call this runnable every 1 sec i.e 1000 delay time
        handler.postDelay(callRandom,1000);
   }
}
```

in onBackground generate the number
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String ranString = "";

```
    Random rn = new Random();

    for(int a = 0; a < 33; a++)
    {
        int i = rn.nextInt(256);

        ranString = ranString + i + " ";
    }
    return ranString;
}
```

this above method will generate the random number string and when it finish this will return that string to the postExecute();

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    if(values!=null & !values.equals(""))
       txtMessage.setText(ranString);

}
```

Comment: I had tried but failed to work with some errors, possible to post the code? @Pratik

Comment: especially on the handler part @Pratik

Comment: The local variable callRandom may not have initialized. I try google to create it but I am not sure how @Pratik

Comment: it's already initialized where you write the code of the callRandom. This will be define in class only not in any method

Comment: Meaning? I still have the error even you said that it is initialized